# Creating pagination with Fishpig

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I'm displaying 3 posts on my homepage and I need to have either a next page, previous page type functionality. I'd also like to incorporate 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, ... type paging functionality on some areas of the site.

I tried doing this:

```
    <span class="page-skips">
        <?php if (($previous = $page->getPreviousPage()) !== false): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $previous->getPermalink() ?>">&larr; <?php echo $this->__('Previous Page') ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (($next = $page->getNextPage()) !== false): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $next->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Next Page') ?> &rarr;</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
```

but getPreviousPage / getNextPage are obviously not functions. any ideas?

Comment: You have already check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55357 (post paging) and this: https://savethefix.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/magento-fishpig-wordpress-integration-set-alternative-pager-for-blog-pages/ ?

Comment: For wordpress please check below link may be it will help you.
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/